# Learning Maven, confused by dependency injection

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, jetty

I'm primarily a JS developer in the process of learning Maven as I move from a Rails house to a Java shop.  The folks at Codehaus have been a huge help in providing a Maven archetype to guide folks like me in understanding how we can leverage Maven to manage dependencies in our codebase:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-ria-archetype/index.html

I mostly understand what they're doing now, but there's one piece they don't explain and I can't figure out where the magic happens.

In the index.html file of their sample RIA app, there's only one line in the HTML to include all the JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="${index.js}"></script>
```

When I run `> mvn jetty:run` on the command line as they suggest to launch the test webapp, the `${index.js}` value is getting replaced with ALL the JS files up the entire dependency tree that are required for the app to function.

Which is great, but I just don't know what part of the process is DOING it.  Can anyone more familiar with this architecture explain it to me? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd assume  it's part of the AMD and AMD plugin processing, built via the process described in the JSRIA architecture page.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I'll see if I can figure out how to read up on the AMD plugin processing to see if that's the actor.

Comment: Yes! That was it, they go into detail here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/js-import-maven-plugin/usage.html
Thank you! If you want to put this in the form of an answer, I'll credit you. Otherwise, I'll answer myself so it's on record in case anyone else ever needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave Newton got me on the right track in his comment to my question. The answer is described in the documentation here:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/js-import-maven-plugin/usage.html

The `JS Import Maven Plugin` that has the artifactId of `javascript-maven-plugin` under extensions in the POM of the Codehaus sample RIA app is responsible for taking the `#{index.js}` string in the index.html file, descending the dependency tree starting with the index.js file, and automatically injecting all dependencies into the HTML.  The exact mechanism the plugin uses for discovering the JS dependencies is described in the usage documentation linked above.